# Creating a shell script to traverse a file system and hash every file

Tags: shell, hash, filesystems, md5sum

I need to create a shell script that will traverse my entire file system, hash each file, and write it into a text database.

I will be doing this on Ubuntu 12.04 and using md5sum and, if we are being honest here, I don't even know where to begin. Any and all help would be appreciated!

Comment: A basic shell script should work fine, you can redirect output into a text file.

Comment: I would start by reading about shell scripting, specifically working with files, and the file system. You'll need to do a tree-traversal so that would be good to read about as well.

Answer (score 3):

This may take some time to compute:

```
find / -type f -exec md5sum {} + >my_database.md5
```

#### How it works

- `find`

  `find` is a utility that can traverse entire filesystems
- `/`

  This tells `find` to start at the root of the filesystem.
- `-type f`

  This tells `find` to find only regular files
- `-exec md5sum {} +`

  This tells `find` to run `md5sum` on each of the files found.
- `>my_database.md5`

  This tells the shell to redirect the output from the command to a file.